# Coil (Subcompose)AsyncImage onSuccess/onError callbacks are not always called

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I have a Composable function with `AsyncImage` to download image from server (I simplified function to make it more understandable):

```
@Composable
fun BannerReference(
    onImageLoadingState: (State) -> Unit = {}
) {
        SubcomposeAsyncImage(
            model = image,
            onLoading = { onImageLoadingState.invoke(it) },
            onSuccess = { onImageLoadingState.invoke(it) },
            onError = { onImageLoadingState.invoke(it) },
            contentDescription = null,
        )
}
```

This Composable is called several times in foreach cycle:

```
referralProgramsData.mgmParams.products.forEachIndexed { index, product ->

            BannerReference(
                iconUrl = product.bannerImage,
                iconUrlFromRes = getBannerImagePlaceholder(product.type),
                onImageLoadingState = { state ->
                    Log.d("debuggg", "screen state: ${state}")
                    imageLoadingState.invoke(ImageLoadingStatuses(index, state))
                }
            )
        }
```

Sometimes such logs are obtained (when BannerReference is called twice):

```
2023-08-01 12:03:14.951  8492-8492  debuggg                 D  onLoading
2023-08-01 12:03:14.951  8492-8492  debuggg                 D  screen state: Loading(painter=null)
2023-08-01 12:03:14.967  8492-8492  debuggg                 D  onLoading
2023-08-01 12:03:14.967  8492-8492  debuggg                 D  screen state: Loading(painter=null)
2023-08-01 12:03:15.078  8492-8492  debuggg                 D  onError
2023-08-01 12:03:15.078  8492-8492  debuggg                 D  screen state: Error(painter=null, result=coil.request.ErrorResult@f10cd10e)
```

onError is expected to be called twice, but for some reason it is not. Could you please advice me how to handle situations when onImageLoadingState is called simultaneously and sometimes doesn't seem to be executed?

Comment: Can you please add the relevant code that glues the `sendAction` call with the `processImageLoadingStatus` call so that it is clear which dispatcher is used. Is this a scrollable screen that displays banners/images also off-screen? Can you describe more in detail in what cases you observe this behavior (is it actually when an error occurs?), have you checked that you always get at least one callback invoked in cases when the loading starts for a target banner/image but the `SubcomposeAsyncImage` leaves the composition before the loading completes (is that even a possible edge case)?

Comment: Please also add the code parts where `imagesLoadingStatuses` is created and any other code that accesses this (if any). Is the number of banners/images always a fixed amount and their indexing order does not change? You could try to log the contents/state of `imagesLoadingStatuses` after every modification to see if the state is indeed being changed in the way you expect it to.

Comment: I added some functions and logs. Is it enough to make any conslusions?

Comment: Actuallly I investigated a bit and came to conclusion that the problem starts long before viewmodel. It starts in Composable function. So I will edit question and delete what we don't need

Comment: I have tried a sample with multiple images (where a few of them error) in a `Column` and in a `LazyColumn` and the callbacks are always executed properly. I did notice however that if you use a `Column` (probably same with `Row`) with images that go off-screen and you do *not* make the `Column`(or `Row`) scrollable, then callbacks for `onLoading` are called on all elements, but the `onSuccess`/`onError` callbacks are only called on visible elements. Check if that's what is causing the issue in your case as well.